# R/RStudio changes name of column when read from csv

Tags: r, csv, rstudio

I am trying to read in a file in R, using the following command (in RStudio):

```
fileRaw <- read.csv(file = "file.csv", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

file.csv looks something like this:
[image: file.csv]

However, when it's read into R, I get: 
[image: fileRaw in RStudio]

As you can see `LOCATION` is changed to `ï..LOCATION` for seemingly no reason.

I tried adding `check.names = FALSE` but this only made it worse, as `LOCATION` is now replaced with `ï»¿LOCATION`. What gives?

How do I fix this? Why is R/RStudio doing this?

Comment: Is it R or is it RStudio that is doing this? Run R OUTSIDE RStudio (from the operating system command line) to narrow this down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a [UTF-8 BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#UTF-8) at the beginning of the file. Try reading as UTF-8, or remove the BOM from the file.

> The UTF-8 representation of the BOM is the (hexadecimal) byte sequence
>   `0xEF,0xBB,0xBF`. A text editor or web browser misinterpreting the text
>   as ISO-8859-1 or CP1252 will display the characters **`ï»¿`** for this.

Edit: looks like using `fileEncoding = "UTF-8-BOM"` fixes the problem in RStudio.

Comment: I reopened the file as UTF-8 in RStudio, the problem persists.

Comment: I would suggest using the `data.table::fread()` function that `check.names=T` option allows for header names check (utilizing `make.names()`)

Comment: @jackson5 Looks like RStudio doesn't handle/skip the BOM correctly. In that case another option would be to re-save the file without a BOM (or as plain text if there are no special characters inside).

Comment: I would also suggest opening csv' s with notepad++ in order to get an idea of what is inside the file. Programs such as MS Excel sometimes hide useful information of csv's (e.g. blanks) .

Comment: I re-saved the file as an ANSI .csv, this seems to have fixed the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Using `fileEncoding = "UTF-8-BOM"` fixed my problem and read the file with no issues.

Using `fileEncoding = "UTF-8"`/`encoding = "UTF-8"` did not resolve the issue.